# How should a custom view handle max width?

Tags: android, android-view

Let's say I would like to build a toolbar like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a15lj.png

So, the toolbar have a maximum width, and I would like to add items(Search, Copy and etc) to the toolbar until it reaches its maximum width.

The challenge is that I won't know the dimension of those "items" without actually inflating them.

What's the best way to do it? Does the following plan sound?

```
ViewGroup toolbar;
int remaining_width = max_width;
for item in items:
    view = inflate(item);
    view.measure()
    remaining_width -= view.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (remaining_width < 0) {
         break;
     } 
     toolbar.addView(view);        
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your toolbar view group programmatically or by using xml layout. If you do it programmatically, then in your custom view group you can override onMeasure() and can measure view group child views , then in onLayout you can layout child views according to measured width.

```
public class Toolbar extends ViewGroup{

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); 
        final int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        // measure child views here
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }


     @Override   
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // layout your child views here
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        child.layout(0, 0, child.getMeasuredWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

And if you wish to stick to xml layouts then you can use OnGlobalLayoutListener().

```
ViewGroup toolbar = findViewById();
toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //Layout is now complete so dimens of toolbar and its child views are available 
       int toolbarW = toolbar.getWidth();
       int toolbarH = toolbar.getHeight();
       // you can add fixed child views in xml and if space is available add optional child views programmatically
       // listener will be called multiple times so do null check before adding views
    }
}
```